# Module loads with modprobe but doesn't in boot

Tags: boot, display, boot-issues, modules

I'm trying to get the 3.5"spotspear Waveshare display working following the guide, (can't have more than 2 links,the name of the guide is "I'd like to have some LCD on my Pi")

Problem is that when I'm using the modprobes the guide suggests

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ sudo modprobe flexfb nobacklight regwidth=16 init=-1,0xb0,0x0,-1,0x11,-2,250,-1,0x3A,0x55,-1,0xC2,0x44,-1,0xC5,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,-1,0xE0,0x0F,0x1F,0x1C,0x0C,0x0F,0x08,0x48,0x98,0x37,0x0A,0x13,0x04,0x11,0x0D,0x00,-1,0xE1,0x0F,0x32,0x2E,0x0B,0x0D,0x05,0x47,0x75,0x37,0x06,0x10,0x03,0x24,0x20,0x00,-1,0xE2,0x0F,0x32,0x2E,0x0B,0x0D,0x05,0x47,0x75,0x37,0x06,0x10,0x03,0x24,0x20,0x00,-1,0x36,0x28,-1,0x11,-1,0x29,-3 width=480 height=320
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ sudo modprobe fbtft_device name=flexfb speed=16000000 gpios=reset:25,dc:24
```

everything works, but as soon as I reboot the screen goes blank.

In the `/etc/modules` I've put both the commands.

There is no HDMI attached, I'm using `ssh` to write to the console.

**Update:** 
[This](https://github.com/cdario/waveshare-3.5-Spotpear-for-Rpi/blob/master/README.md) guide it's maybe easier to read,I've tried using the modules it suggests which don't seem that different,but still nothing.

I've also tried downloading and installing [the spotspear drivers](http://www.spotpear.com/learn/EN/raspberry-pi/Raspberry-Pi-LCD/Drive-the-LCD.html) but upon reboot the screen is still white.

The modprobes from `ssh` work fine,but the screen is still white after boot.

Comment: What modprobes?  Perhaps you are following an out of date tutorial.

Comment: These two:
sudo modprobe flexfb nobacklight regwidth=16 init=-1,0xb0,0x0,-1,0x11,-2,250,-1,0x3A,0x55,-1,0xC2,0x44,-1,0xC5,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,-1,0xE0,0x0F,0x1F,0x1C,0x0C,0x0F,0x08,0x48,0x98,0x37,0x0A,0x13,0x04,0x11,0x0D,0x00,-1,0xE1,0x0F,0x32,0x2E,0x0B,0x0D,0x05,0x47,0x75,0x37,0x06,0x10,0x03,0x24,0x20,0x00,-1,0xE2,0x0F,0x32,0x2E,0x0B,0x0D,0x05,0x47,0x75,0x37,0x06,0x10,0x03,0x24,0x20,0x00,-1,0x36,0x28,-1,0x11,-1,0x29,-3 width=480 height=320

Comment: and : sudo modprobe fbtft_device name=flexfb speed=16000000 gpios=reset:25,dc:24

Comment: @joan - For neatness, I've added the `modprobe` lines to the original post. Do note that you do not put the `sudo modeprobe ...` lines into `/etc/modules`, you put the `flexfb...` and `fbtft_device...` lines into `/etc/modules`, as the guide shows. Have you added the former or the latter lines?

Comment: I didn't include "modprobe" in the /etc/modules

Comment: Try adding `device_tree=` (i.e., with no arguments) to `/boot/config.txt`.

Comment: Nope,still nothing.

Answer (score 0):

> In the /etc/modules I've put both the commands.

You only need to list the modules themselves (with any options passed to them in /etc/modules.

So it should look something like:

```
flexfb nobacklight regwidth=16 init=-1,0xb0,0x0,-1,0x11,-2,250,-1,0x3A,0x55,-1,0xC2,0x44,-1,0xC5,0x00,0x00,0x00‌​,0x00,-1,0xE0,0x0F,0x1F,0x1C,0x0C,0x0F,0x08,0x48,0x98,0x37,0x0A,0x13,0x04,0x11,0x‌​0D,0x00,-1,0xE1,0x0F,0x32,0x2E,0x0B,0x0D,0x05,0x47,0x75,0x37,0x06,0x10,0x03,0x24,‌​0x20,0x00,-1,0xE2,0x0F,0x32,0x2E,0x0B,0x0D,0x05,0x47,0x75,0x37,0x06,0x10,0x03,0x2‌​4,0x20,0x00,-1,0x36,0x28,-1,0x11,-1,0x29,-3 width=480 height=320 
fbtft_device name=flexfb speed=16000000 gpios=reset:25,dc:24
```

Comment: Sorry , I don't know the terminology well but I put the right lines in the right places, I didn't include "modprobe" in it,but at boot the screen is still white.

Answer (score 0):

I found a clunky solution that will have to do for now,I created a bash script with the modprobes in it which executes on startup in `/etc/rc.local`.

It does look seamless though.

Answer (score 0):

There are **four different stages/places/ways** of modules auto-load, and let me explain them :

- kernel command-line. It's a must-have modules, from **statically** linked to kernel or from **statically-linked into kernel** initrd. There *must be** your storage controller's drivers, NIC drivers, hardware crypto and firewall things. Theese modules can not be unloaded.
- kernel command-line from initrd(**bad practice sometimes**). Something you need to be up early, like your USB wifi dongle to make your home AP working, e.t.c.
- `/etc/modules.conf` - some non-vital peripherials, like an external TFT/LCD i2c display, i2s sound card - all that can be safely initialized *after mounting all the file systems*, including network ones.
- `rc.local` post-init script. Yes it is! I had a *very odd* problems popping out of nowhere from time to time when I was trying to use ZRam module as a swap provider. Until I removed *any* swap from `/etc/fstab` and added it in rc.local *after all the things are already up and properly configured*.

So - the main part - **none of the levels mentioned upstrings are extra, not one of them is replacing another, all are good for their tasks**. Do not try to replace them to ensimplify things - you will be very disappointed by the glictches like I used to have with ZRam.